# How many people have done a triple triple?

Tags: hiking, appalachian-trail, thru-hike, pacific-crest-trail, continental-divide-trail

Some of the United States' most famous [National Scenic Trails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Scenic_Trail) are the [Appalachian Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_Trail) (AT), [Pacific Crest Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Crest_Trail) (PCT), and [Continental Divide Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_Divide_Trail) (CDT), and when you have hiked all three you can earn the [Triple Crown of Hiking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_Crown_of_Hiking).

There are some who have done a triple-triple, meaning they have hiked all three trails three times.

I have always wondered how many people have accomplished this.

Does anybody know of a list of triple-triples?

Comment: There is barely a record of people who have completed the CDT (I wasn't able to find anything even vaguely official and comprehensive).  I know of one other person who, I believe, has done a triple-triple, named RestStop.

Comment: (From the Wiki): "The American Long Distance Hiking Association - West (ALDHA-WEST) is the only organization that recognizes this hiking feat. [...] As of October 2012, 174 hikers have been designated Triple Crowners."
So... triple-triplers might be mighty rare.

Comment: What would constitute proof? Wouldn't it be fairly easy to cheat?

Answer (score 3):

*As far as anyone knows*, no one has done a triple hike of each of the Triple Crown of Hiking.

That said ...

None of the three trail conservatories keep very rigorous records; instead they make estimates of trail usage based on trail registers and permit applications. Someone can do the full PCT and the PCTA would never know that they reached the end.

The Triple Crown is more of a popularly conceived achievement than a recognized sporting feat; it was popularized in the early 90s. Only ALDHA-WEST keeps records as to who has completed it, and that pretty much its claim to fame. As far I know, they don't have any records of triples, just doubles. But again, there are Triple Crowners who don't know about or bother with ALDHA.

So it's entirely possible an out-of-the-loop hiker has down three Triple Crowns. But there's no good evidence of that.

Anyways...

The evidence for anyone completing 3 Triple Crowns is scant. If someone has done 3 Triple Crowns, and people know about him or her, that hiker would be famous like Andrew Skurka or Scott Williamson. The fact that this question is being asked just shows that the answer is probably "0".

Comment: I have already responded to two nearly identical answers (both of which were removed by those who posted their answers, after my responding) so here goes the same response, third time: cite:  http://blog.altrazerodrop.com/news/lint-bunting-triple-crown-king/ and https://www.instagram.com/p/89YHNgtUeP/ to highlight just one hiker that has done a triple triple, and reference the article for indicate of at least two others.

Comment: There are people who have claimed to have done the Way of St James 100 times, but there is no recognition or proof. Do we take their word at it, or should we be skeptical? IMO some guy's Instagram page and guest blog post is not very good evidence that he did a complete triple triple. He might have, but without thorough documentation or greater recognition/scrutiny, we really can't be sure. Remember that there are many many people who claim to have done the entire PCT or AT - while complete "forgetting" that they skipped hard or time consuming parts.

Comment: But why would anyone want to do this anyway? With hundreds of wonderful trails around the world, why not spread your wings a bit?